# How to control the jump to a bookmark inside a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bookmarks

I'm trying to achieve a page with a certain number of divs, each of which has a bookmark (a name). The problem is, when I jump to one of the bookmarks, part of the text is gone, caused by the design. I'd like to know if there's a way to change the behaviour of the bookmark, so it won't set the start of it at the top of the page, but a set number of pixels below.

The page can be accessed here: Not longer online, sorry.

The behaviour occurs when you go to any of the bookmarks (except #6, because the document ends there), like on here: Not longer online, sorry.

Can this be solved by a css property or any other way? (update) I'd prefer this over a javascript solution because I'm planning to use javascript to tab them, and keep the bookmarks in case of disabled javascript

Comment: The problem is the CSS on your header - `position: fixed;`

Comment: I know that the position is fixed, but I want the header, menu and footer to remain on place, no matter where you scroll in the document...

Comment: @codegrabber—You can simply put the anchor above the div you wish to display. Leave enough space between the anchor and the following heading element for the fixed header. It will create more space between each section, but that likely isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself, so this is basically for references.

To ignore the 100px offset that is caused by the header, I added a [padding-top](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-top.asp) of 100px to each single div element, and then I changed the links to go to the div's instead of the a elements I added. This padding-top basically makes the text appear where it should and thus solved my problem.

Comment: I hope you used a class and added some CSS - else if you want to change the header size your going to have fun changing all that code again.

Comment: Yeah I added a class and css :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JavaScript using `scrollBy`. Put this in a `load` listener or `onload` handler:

```
if(window.location.hash.length > 1) {
    window.scrollBy(0, -60); // Adjust to suit your needs.
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for when javascript is enabled, but is there a way to handle this if javascript is disabled for example? I was planning to make a javascript div changer, and was going to use the bookmarks in case javascript was turned off (probably should have mentioned that)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onhashchange = window.onload = function () {
     if( window.location.hash.length && window.scrollY > window.pageYOffset ) {
          window.scrollBy( 0, -100 ); // Scroll up 100 pixels on hash change
     };
};
```

Comment: Warning - neither `window.scrollY` nor `window.pageYOffset` work on Internet Explorer.